# How to resize UIImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimageview

I have an image in my UITableView cells, but for some cells, I want not to show image, so I decided to set image height size to zero (you know I cannot use Hidden=true) because of remaining blank space.

So, I tried every thing, but I couldn't resize image, here is my code, so how to resize ?

```
    cell!.imageImage.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    cell!.imageImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I also tried:

```
    cell!.imageImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    cell!.imageImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

So what should I do ?

Comment: How is this cell implemented? Is the Auto layout used?

Comment: @Kirsteins Yes, and I used some constrain too.

Comment: cell!.imageImage.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.width - your Image Width, cell.frame.height - Your Image height) try this..

Comment: @DharmeshKheni still did not work.

Comment: have you tried setting image to nil? And maybe making background of the imageView transparent? Can you also provide screenshots? It would be much more easier to answer

Comment: @KonstantinKoval Yes, I tried but did not work. :(

Comment: i have the same problem. my tablecell works fine with all i need beside setting the image height to 0, if no image is loaded. the uiimageview does not change size

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default `UITableViewCell` with `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, you have to subclass the `UITableViewCell` and implement the `layoutSubviews` method, and set the image's frame there.